# making a php app a phonegap app

Tags: php, iphone, web-applications, cordova

Is there a way of making this app: www.benjaminpotter.org/myarden
which uses php, mysql, html, css, javascript and jquery into a phonegap app?

Otherwise how would you make this an ipad app?

Comment: could you accept some of the answers to your questions like this one?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, phonegap can not run PHP, cause it needs a server, it can use only HTML and JS which runs on the client.

You could make an empty iPad app with a Web Container for this URL, or make the provided site an WebApp (specific meta tags for the iOS).